# Why would Command::output block for longer than the subprocess that it spawned?

Tags: rust, multiprocessing, rust-cargo

I have program A which spawns a long running process using [`Command::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn) and returns:

```rust
fn main() {
    std::process::Command::new("sleep").arg("8").spawn().unwrap();
}
```

At the same time, program B calls program A and waits for output:

```rust
fn main() {
    std::process::Command::new("target/debug/programA").output().unwrap();
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

Running `cargo run` in the directory for program B returns in a few microseconds, almost the same time it takes to run program A on its own.

#### Observed Behavior

Program A takes about 200 microseconds on it's own while program B blocks for 8 seconds.

#### What to do?

I have created [a small project](https://github.com/Sythanis/Test-Recursive-Process) that shows this behavior. I have also tried to use other crates such as `subprocess` or `tokio::net::process` in an asynchronous context but all behave the same. This is the first time I have come across this behavior and I cannot find any documentation how to get around it.

Comment: "By default, stdin, stdout and stderr are inherited from the parent." so B wait sleep process to close/write something on its stdout.

Comment: Your question is unclear for me, on one end you use `output` and on the other hand you don't use the output of A program. Why do you use output so ? Why not just use spawn in B like A ?

Comment: @Stargateur, this just might be it. Didn't consider inheritance of Stdio's. This was just an example. I have encountered this problem in the integration testing of a CLI of a daemon I am writing. In particular CLI's `start` method.

The test creates a blocking `Command` that executes the CLI binary which behind the scenes spawns the daemon if it's not running already. Problem was that due to above mentioned problem, Command never returned, and test failed by timeout.

Answer (score 0):

So taking into the account the comment of @Stargateur, I have made a small change and it made it work. All commands pipe or set to null Stdout, Stdin, Stderr, . Such as

```rust
fn main() {
    std::process::Command::new("sleep)
      .arg("8")
      .stdout(Stdio::piped())
      .stdin(Stdio::null())
      .stderr(Stdio::null())
      .spawn()
      .unwrap();
}
```

This fixes the blocking.

#### EDIT

The use of /bin/bash didn't work after some exploration. The subcommand was never triggered. But piping of Stdout, Stdin and Stderr worked.